# Changing View of items in an Adapter linked to a ListView during app execution

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to give the users of my app the option to change how they want their results displayed.

I've created a different layout item for each view and extended from `BaseAdapter` like so:

```
public View getView(int index, View recycledCompatibleView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // Just in case the view can be reused
    View toReturn = recycledCompatibleView;
    if(toReturn == null)
    {           
        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        toReturn = inflator.inflate(layoutId, null);
    }
    ...
}

public void setResultsListStyle(int layoutId)
{
    this.layoutId = layoutId;
}
```

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` is (observable through debug) refreshing the view because the new view is being inflated and returned from `getView()` method.

However the view on screen is not changing...

Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that ListView may cache already inflated `View`s that are of old "format". You need to somehow reset this View "cache". For this you can use next trick:

```
mListView.setAdapter(mListView.getAdapter());
```

Instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.